# Javassist causing IOException on JBoss startup with Java 8 style code

Tags: lambda, jboss, java-8, javassist

JBoss server was working fine. Deployed Java 8 code with streams and lambdas and restarted JBoss. I see the following exception in *jboss.log*. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: invalid constant type: 18
    at javassist.bytecode.ConstPool.readOne(ConstPool.java:1090) [javassist.jar:6.1.0.Final]
    at javassist.bytecode.ConstPool.read(ConstPool.java:1033) [javassist.jar:6.1.0.Final]
    at javassist.bytecode.ConstPool.<init>(ConstPool.java:149) [javassist.jar:6.1.0.Final]
    at javassist.bytecode.ClassFile.read(ClassFile.java:737) [javassist.jar:6.1.0.Final]
    at javassist.bytecode.ClassFile.<init>(ClassFile.java:108) [javassist.jar:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.ejb3.Ejb3Deployment.deployElement(Ejb3Deployment.java:702) [:1.7.21]
    at org.jboss.ejb3.Ejb3Deployment.deployUrl(Ejb3Deployment.java:692) [:1.7.21]
    at org.jboss.ejb3.Ejb3Deployment.deploy(Ejb3Deployment.java:655) [:1.7.21]
    at org.jboss.ejb3.Ejb3Deployment.create(Ejb3Deployment.java:544) [:1.7.21]
    at org.jboss.ejb3.deployers.Ejb3Deployer.deploy(Ejb3Deployer.java:177) [:6.1.0.Final]
    ... 49 more
```

Comment: Which version of JBoss are you using?

Comment: I am using JBossAS 6.1.0 Final

Comment: Well, according to [this discussion thread](https://developer.jboss.org/thread/223739?tstart=0&_sscc=t), provided by JBoss's developers, the support for Java 8 only started with WildFly 8 and following versions.

Comment: @aribeiro Thanks for the link. The JBoss developer does say that. No other option but to upgrade ?

Comment: It is the better option. In fact, that's what Tomaz Cerar recommends: *In any case, I would recommend you to go with WildFly 8.2.0.Final.*.

Comment: It’s obviously the version of the integrated Javassist that can’t handle Java 8 classes (actually, constant type 18 was added in Java 7 though not used by ordinary Java code). If you don’t want to upgrade everything, you have to update Javassist to version 3.17 or newer.

Comment: We had the same problem with JBoss 5.1.0.GA. Fixed with updating javaassist.jar to newest, but admin console broken. Better to migrate to WildFly 10.0

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix JBoss 6.1.0.Final problem with updating dependencies in the project. Both `org.aspectj.aspectjrt` and `org.aspectj.aspectjweaver` are updated from 1.6.0 (used with JDK6) to 1.8.9 (for JDK8).